# How to make screensaver accept other credentials?

Tags: python, gnome, screensaver

Under Windows XP I have seen some commercial software that protects the computer with a USB device. That is, the screensaver activates after a certain period of time as usual. But to deactivate, you need not only a passphrase, but also a USB device plugged in. The device contains certificates and has to be verified before deactivating the screensaver.

I am looking for some way to implement such feature with Python. I have searched in the Ubuntu Software Center and got BlueProximity being the software most close to my purpose but still different. This software monitors a certain Bluetooth device and its presence is used to simulate user activities periodically to avoid screensaver's activation.

Surely I can do a similar program, periodically check a certain USB disk's presence and validate its containing certificate, and if all-OK, poke the screensaver as some user activity, otherwise lock the screen.

However this is not immediate. Suppose someone have stolen my passphrase to unlock the screensaver, but not the USB disk, then he can unlock the screen. And within at least one minute or so the screen should be locked again. Even if my program has a rather short checking period--like 0.1 second, intervals summing from the 0.1s and the slowly fading time cost(usually nearly 1s) exists between one and another lock-up.

So is there any better solution, such as some APIs that my program can tell screensaver refuse to unlock any way?

Comment: The screen should look for the device and NOT lock, as described. However, once it HAS locked, if user action is taken, it should check for device presence BEFORE prompting for password.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look to [PAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) (Pluggable Authentication Modules).  The solution will be more generic, robust and it could be applied to any program that relies on PAM for authentication.